# Battlefield 2 via CrossOver: Graphic Bug With High Terrain

Tags: windows, graphics, virtualization, games, driver

I'm trying to play Battlefield 2 with CrossOver on 10.7.4 but it produces a graphic glitch:

[image: Battlefield 2: Graphic Glitch]

I've already checked the software updates for new graphic-divers but can't find any anything. Is there maybe a way to update the drivers without the `"Software Update..."` seclection from ? Does anyone have ideas how to fix this?

Thanks for every answer!

Answer (score 2):

Unlike on a Windows gaming machine you don't have many choices to fix such issues on a Mac. As far as I know there are no dedicated drivers sections on the NVIDIA or ATI pages and no possible beta-drivers from Apple.

After a couple of years I ended up with a separate Bootcamp partition for the gaming fun because (forgive the harsh words) all the CrossOver, Wine, whatever crap sucks! Take a look in the AppStore and see the comments on Civ V as an example. Even the relatively smooth running and still good looking Eve Online has some glitches.

Sorry for the negative mood, but I think we'll have to wait some more years to see more 'native' mainstream games like Starcraft.

Comment: I've already had the idea, but the problem is I have already Ubuntu as second OS on my Mac and there isn't much space left.